# Interference between crop and (new)geometry

Tags: margins, geometry, crop

I encountered a strange behavior of the command `\newgeometry` when using the `crop` package. After the first call of `\newgeometry` the centering of the page layout is lost and also can not be restored by calling `\restoregeometry`.

**What should I do in order to avoid the loss of the centering?**

Some pictures so you can see what I'm talking about (marked the physical margins with a thin red line):

[image: page 1]
[image: page 2]
[image: page 3]

MWE creating the pages shown above:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
% driver=none is recommended when using geometry and crop together
% geometry documentation - Known problems:
% With crop package and mag not equal 1000, center option of crop doesn't work well.
% Therefore I have added mag=1000 (although it should be the default value)
\usepackage[a4paper,twoside,showframe,driver=none,mag=1000]{geometry}
\usepackage[width=216truemm, height=303truemm, center, frame, noinfo]{crop}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\newgeometry{showframe, margin=1cm, includefoot, includehead, mag=1000}
\blindtext
\restoregeometry
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `\makeatletter\CROP@center\makeatother` after every change of geometry.

Comment: That worked, I think it should be implemented in the next release of `geometry`. Can you post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `\makeatletter\CROP@center\makeatother` after every change of geometry.

Comment: It recenters the page on the new geometry.