# Interference between crop, (new)geometry and iftoggle

Tags: geometry, etoolbox, crop

To center a cropped page in combination with `\newgeometry` one can add

```
\makeatletter\CROP@center\makeatother
```

after each change of geometry (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118824/61658).

Using the `\etoolbox` package, one can define a toggle to switch the cropping on and off via

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{crop}
\settoggle{crop}{true}
```

in combination with

```
\iftoggle{crop}{...}{}.
```

When I do this (see source code below), I get the following error:

> Undefined control sequence. <argument> \makeatletter \CROP @center \makeatother

Removing the toggle fixes the error.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[
    paper=a4,
    DIV=10,
    twoside=true,
    titlepage=on
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[
    pass,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
    \newtoggle{crop}
    \settoggle{crop}{true}

\iftoggle{crop}{
    \usepackage[
        width=21.6truecm, height=30.3truecm,
        cross, axes,
        pdftex,
        center,
        noinfo
    ]{crop}
}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}

% Standard page (right)
\Blindtext[2]

% Centered page (left)
\newgeometry{centering}
%%% TODO Delete following line to fix error.
\iftoggle{crop}{
    \makeatletter \CROP@center \makeatother
%%% TODO Delete following line to fix error.
}
\Blindtext[2]
\restoregeometry
%%% TODO Delete following line to fix error.
\iftoggle{crop}{
    \makeatletter \CROP@center \makeatother
%%% TODO Delete following line to fix error.
}

% Standard page (right)
\Blindtext[2]

% Standard page (left)
\newpage
\Blindtext[2]

% Standard page (right)
\newpage
\Blindtext[2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `\iftoggle` has *three* arguments.

  ```
  \iftogle{<toggle>}{<true>}{<false>}
  ```

  You're missing the `<false>` case *each* time you use it (also in the preamble)
- put `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` *outside* of the conditional. Once it has read (and tokenized) its arguments the `@` of `\CROP@center` can't be changed any more. That's why the change has to happen before the argument is read.

  ```
  \makeatletter
    \iftoggle{crop}
      {\CROP@center}
      {}
  \makeatother
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the solution (and also for correcting the careless mistake with the missing argument of `\iftoggle`)!